# kendo ui mvc5 multiselect as a regular html multiselect

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-mvc

I want to use the Kendo MVC UI MultiSelect as a regular HTML Multiselect.  This will be used as a cascading multiselect list.

So the look and feel of this:

```html
<select id="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
  <option>New York</option>
  <option>Chicago</option>
</select>
```

Should be applied to :

```html
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect().DataTextField("Name").DataValueField("Id")
.DataSource(source => { source.Read(read => { read.Action("GetCities", "Misc"); }); }).Name("CitySelect")
    .Enable(true))
```

I don't want to use a dropdown so if you can let me know if i can do this, I would appriciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<select id="multiselect" multiple="multiple"></select>
<script>
var data = ["One", "Two"];
$("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
  dataSource: data
});
</script>
```